# Peanut butter becomes dry

Tags: peanuts, peanut-butter

I tried to make some peanut butter at home in a blender. It worked as expected, resulted in a somewhat smooth butter.

But after keeping it for about 30 minutes, it became too dry. The smoothness was all gone and started to appear powdery. How can I avoid this?

I had added some honey and a little bit of coconut oil.

Answer (score 4):

It's a natural process in homemade peanut butter (and in 100% peanut butters). The fat from peanuts is stratifying from the rest. This is assuming you keept the mixture in the machine for longer time. So A) you squished the fat and b) mixed the fat in again.

If you stopped blending right after you "buttered" it then the fat is still not homogenised. Just toss it again in blender and blend for another few minutes. The mixture should be homogenous but when you take  little on finger or spoon and shake it off the oily film should be left.